# Why is TypeScript generating an IIFE for a class?

Tags: javascript, class, typescript

Looking at this TypeScript code:

```
class Greeter {
    greet() {}
}
```

It generates an IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) around the constructor function and all prototype function declarations like:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
    function Greeter() {
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () { };
    return Greeter;
}());
```

What is the advantage here? When ever I read about IIFE I see a lot usage in defining modules. As far as I can see Typescript does not generate anything inside the IIFE that would pollute the global namespace.

In my opinion there is no advantage over this class declaration:

```
var Greeter = function () {}
Greeter.prototype.greet = function () { };
```

**What is the reason for it?**

Comment: Probably to simplify TypeScript's code so it doesn't have to guess when it needs an iife or not, that's the advantage. It doesn't really matter, does it? If this were hand written code, you'd have more of a point

Comment: For the guys who voted to close this question: It's not opinion based. The TS compiler does it this way, and the question is why. I assume there is at least some reason behind this decision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is interesting. I think the typescript compiler compiles `ClassDeclaration` deduced from `ClassExpression`s, by assigning the expression to a variable in the scope, so they don't have to handle those cases independently. This simplifies the TypeScript compiler, and makes the generated code somewhat modular (I would say more readable, but that's just a matter of taste).

```
class Bar { };
foo(class Baz { });
var Baa = class Bab { };
```

Compiles into:

```
var Bar = (function () {
    function Bar() {
    }
    return Bar;
}());
;
foo((function () {
    function Baz() {
    }
    return Baz;
}()));
var Baa = (function () {
    function Bab() {
    }
    return Bab;
}());
```

See, the `ClassDeclaration` is compiled as a `ClassExpression` assigned to a local variable.

Answer (score 12):

To avoid global namespace pollution.

Its a clousure pattern where inner functions have access to their parents properties. By IIFE, REFERENCE to inner functions returned.

Below are two scenarios, where IIFE pattern is quite helpful and the reason, why TypeScript Compiler generates IIFE pattern:

1. Inheritance implementation: where it passes the `BaseClass` as an argument to IIFE. If IIFEE would not have been there `BaseClass` would be global variable, thus polluting the global namespace.

**TypeScript**:

```
class Greeter extends BaseController {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}
```

**JS**:

```
var Greeter = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Greeter, _super);

    function Greeter(message) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    };
    return Greeter;
}(BaseController));
```

2. Module pattern implementation: where app has only one global variable like 'app' and all other features are wrapped into objects like `app.cart`, `app.catalog` etc. There only variable is exposed through modules and all other features are added to the modules itself, which is possible by IIFE only.

**TypeScript**:

```
module App.Controller {
    export class Greeter extends BaseController {
        greeting: string;
        constructor(message: string) {
            this.greeting = message;
        }
        greet() {
            return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**:

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    var Controller;
    (function (Controller) {
        var Greeter = (function (_super) {
            __extends(Greeter, _super);
            function Greeter(message) {
                this.greeting = message;
            }
            Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
                return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
            };
            return Greeter;
        }(BaseController));
        Controller.Greeter = Greeter;
    })(Controller = App.Controller || (App.Controller = {}));
})(App || (App = {}));
```

Copy/Paste this js code to browsers console and only App variable will be globally created. Rest functionality will be under App.

Thanks,
mkdudeja

Comment: OP stated that the code would not pollute the global namespace, and I dont see how would that pollute the global namespace either. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Just because the reference to the inner function is immediately assigned to a variable with the same name

Comment: If you are right, please find an example that would pollute the global namespace. 
All variable declarations of the class happen on the prototype. I read through the typescript class documentation and did not found anything.

Comment: edited the post and added code snippets & explanations.